# return does not retrieve all data from while loop

Tags: php, function, mysqli, return, echo

So I am having some difficulty understanding why, If i use return on the end of my function it does not return all the values but only one.
But if I use echo, all values get displayed. 
New to functions and trying to understand and make use of them more. Any explanation is much appreciated.

```
function find_all_users($Teacher_role) {
global $mysqli;
if ($Teacher_role == "teacher") {
    $set_update_role = "teacher";
}
$set_visable = 1;
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_email, first_name, last_name, role FROM users WHERE role = ? AND visible = ? ORDER BY user_id ASC"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
/* 2 Bind params */
if (!$stmt->bind_param("si", $Teacher_role, $set_visable)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
/* 1 Execute statements */
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
$result = $stmt->get_result();
// output data of each row

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $user_id = $row["user_id"];
    $user_email = $row["user_email"];
    $user_Fname = $row["first_name"];
    $user_Lname = $row["last_name"];
    $user_role = $row["role"];

    $output = "<tr>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $user_id . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $user_email . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $user_Fname . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $user_Lname . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td>" . $user_role . "</td>";
    $output .= "<td> <a href='update_" . $set_update_role . ".php?id=" . $user_id . "'>Edit</a>" . "</td>";
    $output .= "</tr>";
    return $output;
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);}
```

Comment: Take a look at the manual of: `return`, it will immediately stop the function and all code after it won't be executed.

Comment: So in this case I should use "Echo" ? or Is there a way to do it with "return" ?

Comment: You can store the data in an array and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not return $output in the while loop. Your $output value is returned immediately upon first run of the loop. Let the while loop build $output for all values and only after everything is completed return $output.

```
   $output = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $user_id = $row["user_id"];
        $user_email = $row["user_email"];
        $user_Fname = $row["first_name"];
        $user_Lname = $row["last_name"];
        $user_role = $row["role"];

        $output .= "<tr>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $user_id . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $user_email . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $user_Fname . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $user_Lname . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td>" . $user_role . "</td>";
        $output .= "<td> <a href='update_" . $set_update_role . ".php?id=" . $user_id . "'>Edit</a>" . "</td>";
        $output .= "</tr>";

    }

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

    return $output;
```

Comment: I still only get one row returned. But now it is the last one in the database instead of the first one.